# IE 6 problems... help?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

http://tendonaid.com/

That's the website.

The top and bottom navigation seem to be off in IE 6. What can I do to fix that?

Comment: You can fix it by not caring about a ten-year-old browser.

Comment: yeah, ie 6 is actually the problem.... +1 @peter

Comment: All above comments true but not really helpful to Maddy

Comment: @Maddy I noticed you use Google Analytics. Could you tell your IE6 share?

Comment: @Ben I couldn't agree more. Sometimes IE6 support is required, for example if dropping it results in lost revenue. Blindly replying with "drop IE6" is naive as every site will have different requirements.

Answer (score 6):

Couple of things that might help you:
IE6 does not recognise well html5 tags like `<header>` and `<footer>`

There's a few solutions to fix this. You could try [John Resig' shiv](http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-shiv/)

Then if that's not enough, you can add an IE6-only stylesheet to fix up the layout for that browser.

See [this article about it](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/).

Comment: +1 @Ben: You IE6 supporter... :-)

Comment: @blunders. IE6-bashing is so 2010.

Comment: Not bashing IE6, also not supporting it -- for that matter, neither is Microsoft (http://support.microsoft.com/gp/lifesupsps/#Internet_Explorer) as far as I'm able to tell.

Comment: @blunders. My point is, we all know now that ie6 is bad, we've read the countless articles on it, bla bla bla, give it up. There are cases where you might need to make it work in IE6 (a client or committee commissioning the website still using ie6 is a good one, or their customer base still does). Answering with "don't support ie6" is not helping someone who _has to_ make it happen. 
SO isn't meant to be subjective website, it's kinda sad that Peter's comment on the OP question gets so many upvotes really.

Answer (score 2):

Per Ben's suggestion of using John Resig' shiv is a valid use of getting content to use the same css styling in IE6. But a more relaible way is to use IE specific conditional statements, this will make sure that browsers with javascript disabled will still render properly.

### In Head

```
 <!--[if IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-ie6.css" />
 <![endif]-->
```

### Body Code

```
 <!--[if IE 6]>
    <div class="footer">
 <![endif]-->
      <footer>.......</footer>
 <!--[if IE 6]>
    </div>
 <![endif]-->
```

You will only need the styling for the additional classes in the style-ie6.css

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that technique too, good find. Could lead to some pretty lengthy source code if that needs to be applied to every other html5 tags in the document

Comment: @Ben. Unfortunately that is the pain of supporting older browsers.

Comment: The only other solution is to not use HTML tags and stick with <div class="footer"> and change your style sheet accordingly. This is what my practice is when I program pages and templates.